# How to do a local rewrite?

Tags: agda

Is it possible to do a local rewrite in the vein of Idris' [rewrite .. in](http://docs.idris-lang.org/en/latest/tutorial/theorems.html)? Being able to do rewrites only in top level functions is a massive annoyance and is literally preventing me from dealing with some problems.

Comment: You can use `subst`. Other than that, no it's not possible.